# What is the Syntax error in this code that detects an even or odd number in python?

Tags: python

Here is the code that the syntax is on:

```
# Odd or Even?
print('Hello! What is your name?')
PlayerName = input()
print("Hello, "  + PlayerName + "! Enter your number and I\'ll tell you if it\'s even or odd!")
PlayerNum = input()
Decimal = PlayerNum % 2
if Decimal == 0.5
print('Your number is odd!')
else
print('Your number is even!')
```

It gives syntax on line 7 (if Decimal == 0.5). Let me know if there are any other errors. I'm also using python 3. What's the problem?
Thanks

Comment: `PlayerNum = int(input())`

Comment: Ummm what does this do?

Comment: Also `Decimal == 0.5:`

Comment: Sorry im kinda new to python

Comment: That converts your input to an integer. In actuality input is read as strings. You need to convert it.

Comment: It is also missing the indentation

Comment: it also says syntax where it says else

Comment: You need colons - `:` - after your `if` clause and after your `else` clause as well. You also need to indent your code (preferably four spaces).

Comment: Please indent your code sample properly. Indentation in python matters.

Comment: So when I run it, it says this:

Comment: Please edit your post to include the information from your comment.

Comment: Hello! What is your name?
BOB
Hello, BOB! Enter your number and I'll tell you if it's even or odd!
14
Your number is even!
>>> 
 
Hello! What is your name?
bob
Hello, bob! Enter your number and I'll tell you if it's even or odd!
7
Your number is even!
>>>

Comment: When i run it and enter a odd number it says its even, why?

Comment: @LOL because the rest of the division `7/2` is `1` and it is not equal to `0.5` (`if Decimal == 0.5`). You should compare it with `0` for example: `if playerNum % 2 == 0:`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
print('Hello! What is your name?')
playerName = input()
print("Hello, "  + playerName + "! Enter your number and I\'ll tell you if it\'s even or odd!")
playerNum = int(input())
if playerNum % 2 == 0:
    print('Your number is even!')
else:
    print('Your number is odd!')
```

- You need to insert a colon after `if` and `else` conditions.
- The input is read as a `string`, you need to convert it to `int` or `float`
- You need to indent your code (I recommend 4 spaces)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly it!